# Pi in the Bible

Tags: contradiction, 1-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does 1st Kings say that pi = 3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/567/does-1st-kings-say-that-pi-3)

This is a standard question often asked about the accuracy of the Bible.

> And he [Hiram] made a molten sea, ten cubits from the one rim to the other it was round all about, and...a line of thirty cubits did compass it round about....And it was an hand breadth thick...." — 1Kings 7:23,26

How can this be since circumference is 3.14 times the diameter?

Comment: Good question!  But since it's already been asked in another form, I cast the deciding vote to close as duplicate.  Even so, this is another way that people might be able to find us via Google.  ;-)